# Andre-Oort for conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is Andre-Oort conjecture expected to hold for complex analytic topology? If yes, do the recent results on abelian type Shimura varieties cover this case?

Sorry for my ignorance, but several references seem to deal with Zariski topology. Thanks.

Edit - Let $S$ be an infinite subset of special points Zariski dense in a Shimura variety $Sh$. Can we characterise when it is also dense in the analytic topology? Say, characterisation in terms of tori giving rise to the special points in $S$.

Comment: Could you please at least provide some links?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The André-Oort conjecture is about the special points of a Shimura variety that lie on a subvariety — it claims that if there is a Zariski dense set of those points, then the subvariety is special as well. (No need to know what special means, here.)

Since the Zariski topology is coarser than the complex analytic one, it would be a stronger assumption that there is a dense set of points, and the resulting theorem would be weaker.

On the other hand, it is known (but non-trivial) that the special points are dense in a special variety for the complex analytic topology.

Comment: Maybe the answer to the following is implicit in your response. Let $S$ be an infinite subset of CM points on a special variety $Sh$. Suppose it is Zariski dense. Can we say that $S$ is also dense in the analytic topology? Please note that $S$ is just an infinite subset of CM points and the non-trivial fact you mentioned is about the analytic density most of the special points on $Sh$ - at least in the references I have seen. Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not true. Take for a Shimura variety the simplest of all, namely the $j$-line parameterizing elliptic curves. It is known (but non-trivial) that the CM points are dense for the analytic topology, but for an arbitrary set of CM-points to be Zariski dense, it is enough that it be infinite. So consider any infinite set of CM-points which are located in a given disk — it will be Zariski dense but not analytically dense.

Comment: Can we characterise $S$ as before so that it is also dense in the analyitc topology? It would be quite interesting to have a characterisation in terms of the tori giving rise to the CM points in $S$.